# Complex integral and Laurent series

Tags: integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Could you help with solving this complex integral: $$\int_C z^3\exp{\left(\dfrac{-1}{z^2}\right)} dz$$ where $C$ is $|z|=5$. I am expecting that the Residue Theorem will be needed. The answer should be  $i\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

$$z^3e^{-1/z^2} = z^3 - \frac{1}{1!} z + \frac{1}{2!} \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{3!} \frac{1}{z^3} + \frac{1}{4!} \frac{1}{z^5} - \cdots$$

What happens when you take your contour integral of that sum? Which terms have non-zero residue?